# When image unavailable, place default image

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code, which uses url's from json file, but sometimes no photos are available and I need to place "NO IMAGE" instead. I tried "onerror" and "fallback-src", but without any success. Could you suggest something, please?

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in artists.programmeField" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
    <img ng-src="URL/{{item._photos[0]._id}}.jpg" fallback-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/2000px-No_image_available.svg.png" class="padding-vertical">
    <p>{{item.startField.slice(8,10) + ":" + item.startField.slice(10,12)}}</p>
    <h2>{{item.titleField[0].valueField}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.descField[0].valueField}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: to show image <span data-ng-show="item._photos[0]._id"><img.........></span>   to show default image <span data-ng-show="! item._photos[0]._id"><img.....>L</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.ngSrc = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png";
  $scope.errSrc = "https://developers.google.com/games/services/images/branding/ic_play_games_badge_green.png";
});

app.directive('errSrc', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('error', function() {
        if (attrs.src != attrs.errSrc) {
          attrs.$set('src', attrs.errSrc);
        }
      });

      attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function(value) {
        if (!value && attrs.errSrc) {
          attrs.$set('src', attrs.errSrc);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
}
input {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h2>Blank ngSrc</h2>
  <img ng-src="" err-SRC="http://google.com/favicon.ico" />

  <h2>Image doesn't exist</h2>
  <img ng-src="smiley.png" err-SRC="smiley2" />

</body>

</html>
```

Create a directve `errSrc`

**directive**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive('errSrc', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('error', function() {
        if (attrs.src != attrs.errSrc) {
          attrs.$set('src', attrs.errSrc);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**html**

```
<img  ng-src="URL/{{item._photos[0]._id}}.jpg" err-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/2000px-No_image_available.svg.png" class="padding-vertical">
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this the best possible way?

Comment: @benzata Yes.Could you please accept my answer,If the answer helps you

Comment: @benzata Glad to help you